# Twitter Bootstrap LESS with Node.js & Express

Tags: node.js, express, twitter-bootstrap, less

Since [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) 2 is out, I wanted to integrate that into my Node.js project. Unfortunately, there's something wrong with the less compiler and I can't get it to work. I put all files into the public folder and set up a new project with `express -c less newproj`.  and added the lines for less

```
less = require('less');
app.use(express.compiler({ src: __dirname + '/public', enable: ['less'] }));
```

All Node tells me is:

```
Express server listening on port 3000 in development mode
undefined
```

On the client side I get a 500 (Internal Server Error) for the bootstrap.css file, which should be compiled by lessc.

```
lessc bootstrap.less
```

Works fine.

Anybody knows how to solve the issue?

Comment: What other middleware do you have running? static? Do you know what is logging the undefined to console?

Comment: Nothing else. It's a completely fresh project and I only changed those two lines and the layout.jade file. No clue where the "undefined" is coming from either.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For posterity, this has changed a lot in recent Express:

```
app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// This is just boilerplate you should already have
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
```

Comment: ok, i've installed less-middleware. my less file (styles.less) is in /public/stylesheets/styles.less --- how do I get styles.css?

Comment: @barraponto use href='/stylesheets/styles.css' and the css is automatically generated

Comment: A little late to the party, but I actually recently created an npm module to easily create an express site with twitter bootstrap. Supports all view engines that express supports, and it also has support for LESS. I plan on adding SASS and STYLUS in the near future as well. It's called quickstrap, you can grab it here: https://npmjs.org/package/quickstrap

Comment: Thank you for showing where to place the less-middleware and static lines, I had them at the end after app.router, and it did not work until I did it in the same order as your answer.

Comment: Thank you, those static middleware also need to precede `app.use(app.router);` — important! :-)

Answer (score 11):

Ok, here is what I have found for you.
First you need both the compiler and the static middleware. The compiler compiles your less and recompiles on changes, the static middleware does the actual serving of the css

```
app.use(express.compiler({ src : __dirname + '/public', enable: ['less']}));  
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Second, for some reason when the compiler runs it is losing the current path information, so it can't find the includes. So I had to go through the bootstrap.css and add the path to each import.

```
@import "/public/stylesheets/reset.less";
```

This is clearly odd, I am going to dig into it further.

Edit: While odd, a deep look through the code shows me no simple way around it. A bit more searching found this pull request on the connect repo https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/pull/174 which offers a fix for this, but the devs don't seem to want it.

There are also some workarounds in that thread, but it seems the best idea is to absolute path your includes.

Comment: See @GoldenBoy's solution for an update on this. You should use less-middleware.