# Twitter boostrap.less in Express

Tags: node.js, express, less

I followed this [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173935/twitter-bootstrap-less-with-node-js-express) to try to configure Twitter's boostrap.less under Node 0.6.12 and Express 2.5.8:

app configuration:

```
app.use(express.compiler({src: publicDir, enable: ['less']}));
app.use(express.static(publicDir));
```

stylesheet link:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.css' />
```

boostrap.less is the vanilla bootstrap.less file from bootstrap 2.02. the code section of it starts with:

```
// CSS Reset
@import "/public/stylesheets/reset.less";
```

When node is fired up and the page requested, the less paths get resolved correctly but the less parser throws an error:

```
../node_modules/less/lib/less/parser.js:385
        throw new(LessError)(e, env);
```

The error causes node to crash after returning a 500 error for the contents of the boostrap.css file.

Any ideas how to get bootstrap.less to work in my setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought, but if you have Twitter's bootstrap.less via a git submodule, do you need to update the submodule? (we made that mistake, and had the same error as you until we realized it and fixed it)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.