# Express.js + Less: How to configure properly

Tags: node.js, express, less

I tried modules 'less' and 'less-middleware'. I tried all the different code-snipplets I have found in all the tutorials. There is no documentation available. Can someone please explain how to configue Express.js and Less, so that less is getting precompiled properly?!

Use the following questions as a guideline:

1. Shall you use either the 'less' **module** or the 'less-middleware' module? What is the official/supported way? What is superior?
2. How should your **directory-structure** in `/public` look like? (any specific folders you need? 'styles'/'less'/'css'? or is it up to yourself?)
3. How to configure your **express app** regarding your directory-structure (from question 2). (static files and compiler options or less-middleware, what directories are important here)
4. How to **reference** my precompiled **stylesheet** from the html? (with .less or .css? what reference type? What directory-path?)

Would be so nice if someone could answer that :-)

Comment: My advice would be to use grunt to pre-compile less, then have node.js serve that content.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***This solution does only work for express 2.x.***

I have found a solution, this hopefully helps someone:

---

**1. less or less-middleware**

I am using less because I have read it is the official port. But not sure what the difference is since there is no documentation available.

**2. directory structure:**

Your directory structure doesn't matter for less. But it is highly recommended to have a public folder that serves all the static content like JavaScript, , Less, CSS or Image files.

**3. App config:**

You need two specific things to make less working properly:

First, the compiler, that compiles the less files:

```
    app.use(express.compiler({ src : __dirname + '/public', enable: ['less']}));
```

And second, show express where to find the static files!

```
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Both should point to your public folder!

**4. The html**

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/bootstrap.css">
```

Point directly to your root-less file, that lies somewhere in your public folder.

**5. The Less Files**

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9174969/389430) answer I know what went wrong all the time. There is kind of a bug in less.js. It will not find all the less files that you import in your root file. So **you have to add the correct path to every import!!!**

Replace 
`@import "reset.less";` 
with 
`@import "/public/styles/reset.less";` 
for every import you have!

**et voilà... :-)**

---

Thank's to everyone who helped with this issue. Also have a look at Wes Johnson's answere. I think he has a very nice solution that somehow didn't work for me...

Comment: express.compiler no longer exists in express 3

Answer (score 4):

Per [this answer (which I also worked on)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10214982/124486). First configure your `app.js`,

```
app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// This is just boilerplate you should already have
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
```

Then simply include the link to the `less` file except change the extension to `css`. Like this,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.css" />
```

And, that will compile `components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less` to css and serve it to your client.

See the [docs on `less-middleware`](https://github.com/emberfeather/less.js-middleware) for more information on how to do cool stuff like minify automatically.

Comment: does less middleware precompile or compile at every request. Is there a way to configure that. Because in development i'd want it to compile per request so i won't need to restart server. But in production i'd want it to compile once and then keep it cached or something. Thanks

Comment: i've been using grunt task to compile less to css manually.. -_-

Comment: @MuhammadUmer internally less-middleware uses a cache, and if you specify *cacheFile* the cache persists between server restarts. Even more joy.

Comment: does persisting cache get updated if less files have been modified if i specify cacheFile.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used less middleware, but I'm not sure how relevant that is for most applications. Most should probably just compile upfront, ie: when you start Node. Could be as simple as this:

```
var fs      = require('fs'),
    less    = require('less');

fs.readFile('styles.less', function(err,styles) {
    if(err) return console.error('Could not open file: %s',err);
    less.render(styles.toString(), function(er,css) {
        if(er) return console.error(er);
        fs.writeFile('styles.css', css, function(e) {
            if(e) return console.error(e);
            console.log('Compiled CSS');
        });
    });
});
```

The directory structure is entirely your preference. I would make use of `express.static` in serving the compiled CSS file.

Comment: I am getting an error from the less parser class -.- strange. I wish there would be a documentation :-(

Comment: there is none, it just doesn't render

Comment: There may be an error with your LESS doc. The above code works fine for me. Tested on Less version 1.3.

Comment: Just saw your update.. I'd suggest not using middleware for the reason I give in my answer. You don't specify a caching option so I'm guessing it recompiles the stylesheet everytime it's rendered... not terribly efficient. This answer compiles once and you recycle the rendered CSS with subsequent requests.

Comment: Now I am getting this error: 
D:\dev\node-backend\Prototyp_Backend\node_modules\less\lib\less\parser.js:390
                        else                                  throw new(LessEr
                                                                    ^
[object Object]